# Как поменять цвет Button по клику на саму Button?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button Eb, Ab, Db, Gb, Bb, Eb2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Eb = findViewById(R.id.E);
    Ab = findViewById(R.id.A);
    Db = findViewById(R.id.D);
    Gb = findViewById(R.id.G);
    Bb = findViewById(R.id.B);
    Eb2 = findViewById(R.id.E2);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void Eb(View view) {
    Eb.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ffaa); // Приложение вылетает
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы инициализируете кнопки, ища их по ID в разметке активити до того, как вы в активити установите разметку.

Т.е. вам надо перенести назначение разметки активити до инциализации переменных для кнопок.

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Eb = findViewById(R.id.E);
    Ab = findViewById(R.id.A);
    Db = findViewById(R.id.D);
    Gb = findViewById(R.id.G);
    Bb = findViewById(R.id.B);
    Eb2 = findViewById(R.id.E2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно описали событие нажатия. Попробуйте так:

```
Eb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Eb.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ffaa)
    }
});
```

Можно сократить (надеюсь правильно):

```
Eb.setOnClickListener(v -> Eb.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ffaa));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно

```
    button_test_h4m.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            button_test_h4m.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_red);
        } else  {
            button_test_h4m.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_blue);
        }
        return true;
    });
```